# Combining deep generic collections

Tags: java, generics

With the following Java code, is there a way to combine collections with related generic parameters at a second level?:

```
public class Tester {

    interface Base{};
    class A implements Base{}
    class B implements Base{}

    @Test
    public void test(){
        Map<String, List<A>> a = new HashMap<String, List<A>>();
        Map<String, List<B>> b = new HashMap<String, List<B>>();

        Map<String, Base> bases = combine(a, b);
    }

    private Map<String, List<Base>> combine(Map<String, List<? extends Base>> one, Map<String, List<? extends Base>> two) {
        Map<String, List<Base>> bases = new HashMap<String, List<Base>>();

        bases.putAll(one);
        bases.putAll(two);

        return bases;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the combine() method will not match `Map<String, List<A>>` to `Map<String, List<? extends Base>>` even though A extends Base and `bases.putAll()` will not accept types of `Map<String, List<? extends Base>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem, in `combine()`, your `bases` is declared as

```
Map<String, List<Base>>
```

but trying to put a

```
Map<String, List<? extends Base>>
```

`List<? extends Base>` is not a subtype of `List<Base>`, just like `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<Base>`.

To fix this, change your `bases` in `combine` to be of type

```
Map<String, List<? extends Base>> bases = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Base>>();
```

Now the `putAll` method accepts any type that extends `List<? extends Base>`. `List<? extends Base>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Base>`.

When you fix that, you have another problem, your `combine` method return type. It now has to be

```
Map<String, List<? extends Base>>
```

so that it can match the `bases` declaration.

This creates a third problem. `Map<String, List<A>>` is not a valid argument for a parameter of type `Map<String, List<? extends Base>>`. You can change the parameter to type

```
Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Base>>
```

Now `Map<String, List<A>>` can be passed as an argument.

So finally, it could look like

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Map<String, List<A>> a = new HashMap<String, List<A>>();
    Map<String, List<B>> b = new HashMap<String, List<B>>();
    Map<String, List<? extends Base>> bases = combine(a, b);
}

private Map<String, List<? extends Base>> combine(
        Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Base>> one,
        Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Base>> two) {
    Map<String, List<? extends Base>> bases = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Base>>();

    bases.putAll(one);
    bases.putAll(two);
    return bases;
}
```

But honestly, do you really need that many levels? Try to make your life easier and, if possible, use something like what [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358769/438154) is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that with generics, `List<Subclass>` is *not* an instance of `List<Superclass>`.

To make your code work, change the type of your source Maps' values to `List<Base>` - you can still add instances of `A` and `B` to a `List<Base>`.

```
public void test() {
    Map<String, List<Base>> a = new HashMap<String, List<Base>>();
    Map<String, List<Base>> b = new HashMap<String, List<Base>>();

    Map<String, List<Base>> bases = combine(a, b);
}

private Map<String, List<Base>> combine(Map<String, List<Base>> one, Map<String, List<Base>> two) {
    Map<String, List<Base>> bases = new HashMap<String, List<Base>>();
    bases.putAll(one);
    bases.putAll(two);

    return bases;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider what you're allowed to do in combine(..)

```
one.put("xxx", new ArrayList<B>());
```

This is valid because the declaration is `Map<String, List<? extends Base>>`.  If you were allowed to pass it `Map<String, List<A>>` you'd mixing types.

If you change the parameter to `Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Base>>` then my example above is not a valid line of code, and you will be allowed to pass `Map<String, List<A>>` to combine(..).